# SQL Server 2008 Select certain columns have specific data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table some of its columns are of a `bit` datatype. I need to select only the `[BIT]` datatype columns and with the value of `[TRUE]`.

I have the following code to select only the `[BIT]` columns from a given table.

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) TableName, c.name ColumnName
FROM 
    sys.columns AS c
JOIN 
    sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id= t.user_type_id
JOIN
    sys.all_objects as o ON o.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE 
    t.name = 'bit' 
    AND o.name = 'TABLENAME' --this is the table name
ORDER BY 
    c.OBJECT_ID
GO
```

Please tell me how to select only those with [TRUE] value

thanks

Comment: Columns don't have values - records do.  It may help to provide sample data and the expected result.

Comment: The tables in the `sys` schema provide metadata for your tables, but don't contain row data for your tables. If you want to query the data in your table you need to join back to your table.

Comment: yes, I know, I need to know how to do it.

Comment: You **cannot** mix the **metadata** about the columns (name and datatype of the columns) with the **actual value** of the columnn the table, inside a single `SELECT` ....

Comment: Ok, as I can see it cannot be done. Vote on deleting the question?

Comment: @Abd-elhameedQuraim - Don't delete your question, just because what you are trying to achieve is not possible does not make your question invalid. There will be others in the future who will think something similar so the answers to this question will help them.

Comment: You can do what you are trying to do. It just does not make sense to do it within a single select statement.

Comment: I was not trying to do it in a single query (NEVER). I was just trying to share and continue the idea with you all. Anyway, I will continue trying with it. I do not give up easily :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use dynamic sql and a temp table with your query to return the values of the columns that are of bit type to true or false.**
Hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL='DECLARE @TempTable table (Value bit,Table_Column nvarchar(500))'
SELECT @SQL=@SQL+';INSERT @TempTable (Value,Table_Column) SELECT '+c.name + ','' '+c.name + ' - ' + o.name + 
     ''' FROM ['
         +o.name + ']' 
         FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
join sys.all_objects as o on o.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'bit' 
and o.name = 'TABLENAME' --this is the table name
ORDER BY c.OBJECT_ID -- columns

SET @SQL=@SQL+';SELECT Table_Column,Value= CASE Value WHEN 0 THEN ''False'' When 1 THEN ''True'' end FROM @TempTable;' 
print @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: I was trying your solution as a last resort, but you were excellent. You did it better than the way I expected to do it. All what I need now is just adding some where clauses to your code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done.  the Sys schema only contains information about objects in your database, not about records in a table.

The only way to possibly do this is to take the information you have and loop through each tablename in your DB, opening each table that your above-referenced view returns, and using a "WHERE ColumnName <> 'NULL'" qualifier in your looping view.

Comment: I provided the sample code for reference only, and I know the sys schema contains only information about objects. I need to know if it is usefull in any way.

Comment: Like I said, you can use the table names that get returned, so you know exactly what tables and columns to check.  But you still have to then loop through the database and query each table to know if the column is set to True or False.  It's definitely the right starting point.

Comment: How to compare object name [system name] to a varchar value returned by the query

Comment: It's gonna be kind of clusterfarked, but you could create a cursor.  I don't know, you'd probably have to put the column names into an array?  I know you can loop through your code by substituting what you have above into the example given here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx  Look at the "Using WHILE in a Cursor" section.